# Free() doesn't work as expected after calling malloc()

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc, free, c99

I wrote the following function in C but have 2 problems:

1. I am asked to free the dynamically allocated memory to prevent using too much RAM but the line `free(word)` just causes bugs to my program.
   if I delete it everything works fine, why is that happening? I used free after I finished using `word` as suggested in many different articles.
2. I am requested to use malloc with the minimum needed space but how could I do that?
   currently my code allocates `max_str_len` blocks of RAM but if the word was much shorter like `a` letter I don't want to allocate 200 blocks for that.
   Any suggestions please?

```
int read_words(char *words[], int size, int max_str_len) {
    char *word;
    char ch;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        word = (char *)malloc((max_str_len + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (word == NULL)
            return -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < max_str_len; ++j) {
            scanf("%c", &ch);
            if (ch == '\n') break;
            if (ch == EOF || ch == 'R') return i;
            word[j] = ch;
        }
        words[i] = word;
        free(word);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: You put `word` pointer to `words` array which comes from the caller, and then you delete it. Don't do that. If you plan to use allocated memory later, don't delete it. This may be the cause for your bug.

Comment: Only call `free` when that what is allocated is no longer needed.

Comment: Do not forget to null-terminate the string, e.g. `word[j]='\0';`

Answer (score 0):

You put a `malloc`'d `char*` into a caller-provided `words[i]` and then you free it. That doesn't make sense. If you free it, the caller can't do anything with it.

If you want the `malloc`'d strings to be minimal you could `realloc` them or you could read into a large buffer (allocated perhaps at the start of the function) and then copy the result into a `malloc`'d buffer that's sized just right.

Note that you're also failing to check `scanf` for errors and that you're leaking memory if you get a memory failure in the middle of the function—by returning -1, you effectively lose info on how many elements of `words` have been filled with owning pointers. You might want to return that info (`return i;`) or to free all pointers allocated by the function before the `malloc` failure.

Comment: but how to free all the pointers? that's my question. As you can see I tried to use free and it didn't work

Comment: @Daniel0909, the question is not _how_ to free the pointers, but _when_ to free the pointers.

Comment: @Daniel0909 In a different function. You're passing `malloc`d pointers to your caller via `words`. Those pointers had better be valid. `free`ing invalidates them. `free`ing doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you free the memory allocated for each word, yet you return pointers to the freed blocks in the array supplied by the caller, causing undefined behavior when the caller will dereference these pointers.
- your test for end of file is incorrect: `scanf()` will return `EOF` then, bu the character will not be set to `EOF`, which might not be appropriate for a `char` anyway. You should use `getchar()` and make `ch` an `int`.
- you should set a null terminator at the end of the string read.
- you could use `realloc` to shrink the block of memory once you know the string length.

Here is a modified version:

```c
int read_words(char *words[], int size, int max_str_len) {
    char *word, *p;
    int i, j, ch;
    for (i = 0; i < size;) {
        word = (char *)malloc(max_str_len + 1);
        if (word == NULL) {
            /* free the words allocated so far and return a failure code */
            while (i-- > 0)
                free(words[i];
            return -1;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < max_str_len; ++j) {
            ch = getchar();
            if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF || ch == 'R') break;
            word[j] = ch;
        }
        if (j == 0 && (ch == EOF || ch == 'R'))
            break;
        word[j] = '\0';
        p = (char *)realloc(word, j + 1);
        if (p != NULL)
            word = p;
        words[i++] = word;
        if (ch == EOF || ch == 'R')
            break;
    }
    return i;
}
```